# PHP SOAP force TLS protocol

Tags: php, ssl, soap, openssl, protocols

How can I force TLS in a PHP SOAP?

I try this but didn't work:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers' => 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:KRB5-DES-CBC3-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5:KRB5-RC4-MD5:KRB5-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-SHA:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-SHA:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5',
        ],
    ]
);
$client = new MySoap($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $context));
```

and keeps returns this error message:

SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure

I will be very glad if someone help me. Thanks.